# How to get webstore top donator per month?

Tags: php, mysql

I created a webstore and I put a top donator per month.

My problem is, how I can get "top donator"?

I try in SQL query `MAX(money)` but have problem on example:

```
test 250

test2 3
```

And say max value is 3

My table:

```
Date    | username | money

2016/7  |  tg95    |   10

2016/7  |  test    |   15
```

How I can get the top donator perm amount?

Here is a table config example:

```
date   | username | money

2016/7 |  test    |   10

2016/7 | test2    |   15

2016/7 | test3    |   9
```

on this example max value is test2 = 15. Maybe more simple is get date (per month) and get a max value on money.

Comment: can you proviide your code , so we can help you

Comment: what kind of problem???? Provide your code.

Comment: The problem is, i try SELECT money MAX(money)
FROM topdonator and say the max value is 3...

Comment: Do not define dolumns containing numerical data as `CHAR`/`VARCHAR`!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT username FROM Table1 ORDER BY money DESC LIMIT 1;
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8eace/5)

Comment: haaaa done is my fault i put table money varch -.-" thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `select` `username` of `max` donator `money` you can use this `sql`

```
select username, money
from youtablename
where money= (
    select max(money)
    from youtablename
)
```

Comment: thanks i try this but continue say the max value is 3 :s

Comment: hey please update your question pasted your table value in and also the result which you want

Comment: so whats the problem you will get test2  if you run my query